# Random 'undefined' gets inserted into string

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes in an integer and returns it in reverse `reverse(-425) -> -524`

```js
let reverse = (x) => {
  let y = x.toString()
  let char = y.length - 1
  let z = ''
  if (y[0] === '-') {
    z = '-'
    y = y.slice(1, y.length)
  }

  while (char >= 0) {
    z += y[char]
    char -= 1
  }

  return z
}

console.log(reverse(-324))
```

When I run `console.log(reverse(-324))` I expect it to return `-423` but instead I get `-undefined423`.

Where is `undefined` coming from?

Comment: So, `let char = y.length - 1` but then you do `y = y.slice(1, y.length)`, so now `y` is *shorter* than it was before and `z += y[char]` is out of bounds.

Comment: [Very helpful resource on how to solve these kinds of issues.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work out the first value of `char` (which depends on the length of the string) **before** you check to see if the number is negative.

If the number is negative you reduce the length of the string by 1 as you remove the `-` from the front.

At this point `char` is one too high.

Change the order you do those things:

```js
let reverse = (x) => {
  let y = x.toString()
  let z = ''
  
  if (y[0] === '-') {
    z = '-'
    y = y.slice(1, y.length)
  }

  let char = y.length - 1

  while (char >= 0) {
    z += y[char]
    char -= 1
  }

  return z
}

console.log(reverse(-324))
console.log(reverse(2468))
```